# Solving a second-order nonlinear ODE with a singularity on x=0

Tags: numerical-analysis

I'm doing some reasearch on electromagnetic nanostructures and I have to solve this differential equation (the exact values of the constants don't matter, I just want **all** the possible solutions of y(x) given some values to these constants).

$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=-\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\sin(2y)}{2} (\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{K}{A})-\frac{D}{A}\frac{\sin(y)}{x}+\frac{\mu HM}{2A}\sin(y)
$$

from x=0 till x=R, with the boundary conditions

$$
y(0)=0,\ \frac{dy}{dx}(R)=\frac{-D}{2A}
$$

I believe you can not find an analitic solution to this equation, so I've been trying to use numerical methods like the shooting method (given the boundary conditions, I found it appropiate).

The thing is that the singularity on x=0 doesn't let me find the solutions. I obtain different results depending on how many steps I take in the method. Do you have any ideas on how I can proceed? Another numerical method maybe?

I also posted this on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292320/skyrmions-solving-a-second-order-nonlinear-ode-with-a-singularity-on-x-0) and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010468/solving-a-second-order-nonlinear-ode-with-a-singularity-on-x-0) StackExchange, but for now I couldn't fix it.

Comment: MATLAB's shooting routine `bvp4c` (see the examples in [this paper](http://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/2009/spring/che512/bvp_paper.pdf)) should be a good fit for this problem. You'll have to treat the singularity first. If you know your solution $y$ is smooth at/around $x = 0$ (this depends on your a priori knowledge about the ODE and its solution), it follows that $dy/dx = 0$. You can then pass this boundary condition to your shooting method routine.

Comment: bvp4c is not based on a shooting approach and, in fact, the cited paper has a good explanation for why basic shooting methods are generally not very robust for solving BVP. The reason a fair bit of trickery is required to use bvp4c for a problem with a singularity at $x=0$ is that you need a mesh point at $x=0$ and bvp4c will try to evaluate the ODE at that point.

Comment: @BillGreene indeed, `bvp4c` is not a shooting code (that's stated explicitly in the paper, a fact that i somehow managed to overlook). nevertheless, it should be useful: if the solution is smooth at $x=0$, then by taking limits $d^2 y / dx^2 = 0$; otherwise, one may attempt a solve on $[\epsilon,R]$ with "small" $\epsilon > 0$ and an asymptotic series approximation of $y$ and its derivatives at $x = \epsilon$, as indicated in example 7 of the reference I've linked to.

Comment: I agree with Tobias's suggestion on MSE to use Taylor series to move the left boundary condition from $y(0)=0$ to $y(\sqrt{\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}}) = \cdots$ and use a shooting method, this is quite straightforward.

Comment: Shouldn't you attempt a change of variable to remove the singularity in 0 ? It seems simple enough to characterise solutions around 0, and then you could have an ODE in terms of some $w$ with, say, $y = x^2 w$.

Comment: This issue frequently shows up in problems posed in spherical or cylindrical coordinates, the so-called "coordinate singularity" or $1/r$, $1/r^2$ behavior that causes issues at the origin. Numerical treatment of the coordinate singularity often shows up in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

If you are content with a numerical solution, then I would suggest using an implicit integration scheme. There are three types of implicit integration schemes, classified by whether or not they require evaluation of the integrand at the endpoints of domain.

- Lobatto:  integrand is evaluated at both endpoints
- Radau:  integrand is evaluated at a single endpoint
- Gauss:  integrand is evaluated at neither endpoint

The simplest Radau scheme is backwards Euler integration:
$$x_{k+1} = x_k + (t_{k+1}-t_k) \cdot f(t_{k+1}, x_{k+1})$$

Each integration step requires a non-linear solve, but it does not require evaluation of the integrand at the initial point. Note that you will need to [put your dynamics into first-order form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015096/how-to-write-a-second-order-dynamical-system-in-first-order-form/2015102#2015102).

For higher-order schemes, checkout Wolfram MathWorld:
[Radau Quadrature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadauQuadrature.html)
[Gaussian Quadrature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianQuadrature.html)

These will both work well, provided that your problem is only singular at the initial point. If there are singularies at other times in the solution, then you need to do something more sophisticated. If this occurs, then the rough approach is to identify when singularities occur and break the problem into continuous sub-problems, where the singularities only occur on the edges of the domain of each sub-problem.